# VSE: How to automatically snap the cursor to the selected strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to automatically snap the cursor to the start (or end) of the selected strip? I know that I can manually move the cursor and if I keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it will snap to the start and end of the strips, but it's not the same as automatically making it jump to the start of the selected strip.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can jump to next/previous strip with page up/down, but there is no function for going to the selected strip specifically.

[image]

Comment: oh ok, thanks tintwotin  ;)